# map_saver for different map topics

Tags: slam, navigation, map-saver, ros-kinetic, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey there.

I am trying to figure out how is possible to use

```
rosrun map_server map_saver -f name_of_map
```

in order to save maps simultaneously made by different gmapping nodes, that is, how to save maps with another topic name than /map.

For instance, /map_1 and /map_2 are being created and the point is to save both maps in different files.

I was watching map_server code in GitHub and found this test launcher:

```
 <launch>

  <node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(find map_server)/test/testmap.yaml"/>

  <test test-name="map_server_test" pkg="map_server" type="rtest"/>

</launch>
```

But I don't know how to modify it in order to accomplish that.
Could you give me a hand?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/314077/map_saver-for-different-map-topics/) by [chbloca](https://answers.ros.org/users/38830/chbloca/) on ROS Answers with karma: 94 on 2019-01-29

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the solution:

```
rosrun map_server map_saver map:=/map_2 -f name_of_map
```

---

Originally posted by [chbloca](https://answers.ros.org/users/38830/chbloca/) with karma: 94 on 2019-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Combinacijus](https://answers.ros.org/users/44007/combinacijus/) on 2020-03-23**:
Thanks, to add full command looks like this (in my case):

```
rosrun map_server map_saver --occ 100 --free 10 -f my_map map:=/move_base/global_costmap/costmap
```